# How can I correctly install Serva TFTP in Windows XP PXE?

Tags: windows-xp, pxe, tftp

I followed the instructions on [this web page](http://www.vercot.com/~serva/an/WindowsPXE1.html) to install Serva, but when I restart Serva, (see *4.3- Quit and Restart Serva*), the folder contents (folders named `WIA_RIS` etc.) aren’t created as described.

I’m using Windows XP Professional SP3.

What could be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to tick the BINL box at the DHCP configuration pane